# change query string parameter

Tags: php, curl

how do I go on about changing query string like for example i have this curl request for an api

```
www.apiurl.com/page=1&content=3
```

i need to request like 60 pages so which is the simple way instead of repeating the code over and over?

like request this in parallel and return the data of all

```
www.apiurl.com/page=2&content=3
www.apiurl.com/page=3&content=6
www.apiurl.com/page=4&content=9
```

code here

```
$strings = array('page'=>'1',                    
                '&content'=>'3');

$postdata = http_build_query($strings);

$data = curl_init();

curl_setopt ($data, CURLOPT_URL, "www.apiurl.com/");
curl_setopt($data, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt ($data, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);

$content = curl_exec($data);  
curl_close($data);
print_r($content);
```

Comment: what is the logic, relation between page / content? page is incrementing by 1, and content with 3?

Comment: i have just given an example there is no logic but the api we are requesting has something like so i was just using this as an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's give a shot to this...

```
//Create an array, what stores, what page and what conent you need
$params = array(
    array('page' => 2, 'content' => 3),
    array('page' => 3, 'content' => 6),
    array('page' => 4, 'content' => 9),
    // and so on
);

define('URL', 'www.apiurl.com/');

foreach ($params as $param) {
    $postdata = http_build_query($param, '', '&');
    $data = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($data, CURLOPT_URL, URL);
    curl_setopt($data, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($data, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
    $content = curl_exec($data);
    curl_close($data);
    print_r($content);
}
```

Comment: I have tried this code and i am getting just white page .. what might be the cause?

Comment: turn on error reporting by `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to inspect what error you you have. But I see what could be wrong. Wait, i will edit my code

Comment: try now, but add those 2 lines at the top of your code as I mentioned in my previous comment.

Comment: the first one worked with xml data only, the second works with both json and xml.. thanks now